# (*C.uchar)(&buffer[0]) vs (*C.uchar)(unsafe.Pointer(&buffer[0]))

Tags: c, go, unsafe-pointers

We have a discussion here over using (or not) `unsafe.Pointer` for passing pointers to byte arrays from Go to C.

What is the biggest reason (not) to use `unsafe.Pointer()` ? I would take consistency as a reason, as you'd call an 'external' function, even in a different language, and you want to guarantee that its a Pointer type.

However, due to the Go language style looking a bit like C, using a straight cast using `(*C.uchar)(&buffer[0]))` is valid *and* works. The fact that it works doesn't make me confident that its *safer* than using `unsafe.Pointer()`.

Maybe I'm a bit confused/conflicted by the Go casts looking like function calls, and `Pointer` being defined as `type Pointer *ArbitraryType` *actually* says `(*ArbitraryType)&buffer[0]` and does *not* actually invoke any command to do the 'conversion' but really just helps explaining what is going on, on a functional level, kind of like a macro *could* do.

Comment: You use `unsafe.Pointer` when you need it. If you're converting _unsafely_ between types, then you're going to need to use the unsafe package to "remove" the type in order to complete the conversion.

Comment: "The fact that it works doesn't make me confident that its safer" -- why? It's safer because it's a valid type conversion. Try it with a different type than can't be converted and see the difference.

Comment: So how exactly is `*byte => *uint8 => *C.uchar` less of a valid conversion than `*byte => *uint8 => *ArbitraryType => *C.uchar` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you change the type (to uint32 for example) without using unsafe, you'll get an error like `cannot convert &buf[0] (type *uint32) to type *_Ctype_uchar`

Comment: Well, yes, that's when you want to interpret the input object as a regular pointer and then convert it to something else. I suppose it is really just a NOP for []byte -> uint8_t* conversions

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following you. You can't convert `[]byte -> uint8_t* `, but you're not doing that, you're converting `*byte -> *uint8` which is safe. (and yes, `uint8`, `byte` and `C.uchar` are all the same type, which is why the conversion succeeds). Also note that many type conversions are "NOP", since you're not doing any action other than changing the declared type for the compiler. (the exceptions are all laid out in the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

Answer (score 4):

The Go documention is littered with warnings against using package `unsafe` to needlessly defeat Go's type system. `unsafe.Pointer` is clearly identified as unsafe for a reason.

---

> [Package unsafe](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/)
>
> Package unsafe contains operations that step around the type safety of
>   Go programs.
>
> Packages that import unsafe may be non-portable and are not protected
>   by the Go 1 compatibility guidelines.
>
> [type Pointer](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer)
>
> Pointer therefore allows a program to defeat the type system and read
>   and write arbitrary memory. It should be used with extreme care.
>
> ---
>
> [Command cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)
>
> [Passing pointers](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers)
>
> Go is a garbage collected language, and the garbage collector needs to
>   know the location of every pointer to Go memory. Because of this,
>   there are restrictions on passing pointers between Go and C.
>
> [These] rules are checked dynamically at runtime.
>
> It is possible to defeat this enforcement by using the unsafe package,
>   and of course there is nothing stopping the C code from doing anything
>   it likes. However, programs that break these rules are likely to fail
>   in unexpected and unpredictable ways.

---

Let's review a realistic example.

Here's a C function that receives a bytes buffer.

```
void printbuf(size_t len, unsigned char *buf)
```

In Go, using cgo and preserving type safety with matching types, we could write,

```
var buf []byte

C.printbuf(C.size_t(len(buf)), (*C.uchar)(&buf[0]))
```

However, that's still unsafe, `buf[0]` will be out of range if `len(buf) == 0`. When `buf` is initialized to it's zero-value the array pointer will also be `nil`.  We can neatly encapsulate the integrity checks in a Go function, which the Go gc optimizing compiler will inline.

```
func cbuf(buf []byte) (size C.size_t, ptr *C.uchar) {
    var bufptr *byte
    if cap(buf) > 0 {
        bufptr = &(buf[:1][0])
    }
    return C.size_t(len(buf)), (*C.uchar)(bufptr)
}
```

and

```
bufsize, bufptr := cbuf(buf)
C.printbuf(bufsize, bufptr)
```

Defeating the type system by using `unsafe.Pointer` is unsafe. For example,

```
C.printbuf(C.size_t(len(buf)), (*C.uchar)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])))
```

The `buf` type could be any indexed type: array, pointer to array, slice, string or map. Even worse, the size, if not one byte, will be wrong. Now it gets get really ugly,

```
C.printbuf(C.size_t(len(buf)*int(unsafe.Sizeof(buf[0]))), (*C.uchar)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])))
```

And we haven't taken into account nil pointers and out of range values.

Next the code review: code should be correct, maintainable, robust, reasonably efficient, and, most importantly, readable. Don't expect the code review of `unsafe.Pointer` usage to go well.

---

Let's hear your rationale for the use of unsafe.Pointer for this purpose.

---

**Sample code**:

`printbuf.go`:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>

void printbuf(size_t len, unsigned char *buf) {
    printf("%lu [", len);
    if (!buf) {
        len = 0;
    }
    size_t maxwidth = 16;
    size_t width = len <= maxwidth ? len : maxwidth;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%02X", buf[i]);
    }
    if (width < len) {
        printf(" ...");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
)

// NOTE: -gcflags='-m' : can inline cbuf : inlining call to cbuf
func cbuf(buf []byte) (size C.size_t, ptr *C.uchar) {
    var bufptr *byte
    if cap(buf) > 0 {
        bufptr = &(buf[:1][0])
    }
    return C.size_t(len(buf)), (*C.uchar)(bufptr)
}

func main() {

    var buf []byte // zero-value = nil, len = 0, cap = 0

    bufsize, bufptr := cbuf(buf)
    C.printbuf(bufsize, bufptr)

    buf = make([]byte, 0) // len = 0, cap = 0

    bufsize, bufptr = cbuf(buf)
    C.printbuf(bufsize, bufptr)

    buf = make([]byte, 0, 32) // len = 0

    bufsize, bufptr = cbuf(buf)
    C.printbuf(bufsize, bufptr)

    buf = make([]byte, 32) // len > 0
    for i := range buf {
        buf[i] = byte(i)
    }

    bufsize, bufptr = cbuf(buf)
    C.printbuf(bufsize, bufptr)

    if len(buf) > 0 {

        C.printbuf(C.size_t(len(buf)), (*C.uchar)(&buf[0]))

        C.printbuf(C.size_t(len(buf)), (*C.uchar)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])))

        C.printbuf(C.size_t(len(buf)*int(unsafe.Sizeof(buf[0]))), (*C.uchar)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])))

    }

}
```

Output:

```
0 []
0 []
0 []
32 [00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F ...]
32 [00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F ...]
32 [00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F ...]
32 [00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F ...]
```